# how to filter the data returned by a previous filter

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have two tables with the below structure

**SalesData**         -----------         **ServiceData**

Vehicle          -----------------             Vehicle

SellDate            ----------------          SDate

The SellDate is the date that vehicle is sold and the SDate is the date of service.

I have a filter that return all vehicles sold between two dates.

I want to perform another filter on the result of the first filter and display the distinctcount of vehicles that came back for service

Comment: the equivalent SQL statement the get the job for me is: SELECT DISTINCT VM_HD_VEHICLE FROM VM_03_HISTDTL WHERE (VM_HD_DOCDATE BETWEEN '01/01/2019' AND '01/31/2020') AND VM_HD_VEHICLE IN 
(SELECT VM_VE_VEHICLE FROM VM_00_VEHICLE WHERE VM_VE_SELDATE BETWEEN '01/01/2019' AND '01/31/2020')

Comment: Give a sample data and expected output#